# When did the silencing of 'h' start?

Tags: language-evolution, spelling, augustinus

I am reading (a bilingual version of) Augustine's *[Confessions](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/augustine/conf1.shtml)*, and I stumbled upon:

> si contra disciplinam grammaticam sine adspiratione primae syllabae hominem dixerit (1.18.29)

Roughly translated to: "if, against the rules of grammar, one pronounces "hominem" without exhaling the first syllable..." As a native Romance speaker, for whom the 'h' was always muted, this reference caught me off guard!<sup>1</sup>

Is Augustine referring to a common spoken error in the non-educated people?

After a quick search on the web:

- [Some sources](https://ssulinguafranca.org/2009/01/09/ask-the-linguist-the-story-of-h-by-dr-jon-aske/) mention "by the time Latin became the language of the Iberian Peninsula (Hispania) [the 'h'] had ceased to be pronounced." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_conquest_of_the_Iberian_Peninsula) dates the Roman conquest of the Peninsula from 206 BC to 19 BC. I don't know when was Latin adopted as spoken language.
- Augustine is from the 3rd and 4th centuries. From the Confessions it looks like the spelling without exhalation is a common error at the time.
- [Appendix Probi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendix_Probi), possibly contemporaneous of Augustine, mentions "adhuc non aduc" and "hostiae non ostiae" as common mistakes.

**Question:** Do we know when did the *silencing* of 'h' start?

<sub><sup>1</sup> I never had a Latin course and I have never spoke Latin. I have only heard "Mass Latin". I had always assumed a silent 'h' as in Romance languages, though I now understand the (historical) reason for the letter 'h' in our words derived from "homo" and "historia".</sub>

Comment: It depends what you mean by "correct". There was a _very_ long period where most people didn't pronounce the `/h/` but educated speakers tried to preserve it—all the way into Romance!

Comment: @Draconis Fair point! I guess I should re-frame my question... to when did the silencing start. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I did hear (although I cannot remember where, to give proper attribution) that the _opposite_ phenomenon occurred for a long time, with aspiration inserted in words that did not have it, generally causing the confusion of the two classes of words.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Before the late Republic

Already in Republican inscriptions we find people leaving off H's, as in *Oratia* for *Horatia*, or adding them where they don't belong, as in *havet* for *avet*. During this time, knowing where H's belonged and where they didn't was a mark of refinement, and Catullus makes fun of a man who tries to appear educated by saying *chommoda* and *hinsidia*.

But from the very earliest surviving texts, there are H's missing that ought to be there etymologically, especially in "rustic" words like *anser*. It seems likely that certain dialects lost the `/h/` sound very early, and for some words this H-less pronunciation became standard across Latin. Even Catullus and his elite, refined circle probably didn't realize that *anser* "should" properly be **hanser*.

In positions other than the start of a word, it was lost even earlier (even in the most prestigious dialects), and we never see *nēmo* written as **nehemo* or *liāre* as **lihāre*.